# Reuse user resource route for current user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've created a resource route for users.

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

My controller handles the path `/user/1/edit` with in my users controller like so:

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $user);
    ...
```

The template for this page is: `resources/views/users/edit.blade.php`.

How would I define a new route, `/user/edit`, which dynamically passes the current user and reuses the `edit(User $user)` method while also reusing the same view template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `edit()` method will need to change to conditionally accept the `User` model. You then need to check if `$user` was passed, else assume current user is required:

```
public function edit(User $user = null)
{
    $user = $user ?: auth()->user();

    $this->authorize('update', $user);

    ...
```

And create the new route:

```
Route::get('user/edit', 'UsersController@edit')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Route::get('users/{user}/edit', 'UserController@edit')->name(edit-user);
```

Then, pass in the user id in route like this:

```
route('edit-user', ['user'=>$user->id]);
```

I hope this helps you.